# Short story; Aliens look for Playboy bosoms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a short SF story I read approx 40 years ago. Unremembered anthology in the UK.

An alien scout party beam up or abduct a man and a woman, strangers to one another, from some American road. The aliens strip them and inspect and then discuss their physique.

The alien captain asks if the woman is defective because she has small pert bosoms, he has a copy of a magazine translated as 'Recreation Lad' and, in the images of that magazine, bosoms are depicted as large globes.

The captive man assures the captain that the woman is fine, pleased with this the captain then asks them to mate so his science team can study the mating process.

Upon refusing, and following several heated discussions, the aliens release the humans after allowing them to get dressed.

It ends with the pair chatting near their cars and knowing that nobody will ever believe them. I think they then decide to go on a date.

Comment: sounds like the title of mystery or scifi recapped video

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Playboy and the Slime God](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?187265) by Asimov, aka [What is this Thing called Love](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40795).

> “The bosom does not consist of globes or spheres. I know what globes or spheres are and in these pictures you have shown me, they are so depicted. Those are large globes. On this creature, though, what we have are nothing but small flaps of dry tissue. And they’re discolored, too, partly.”
>
> “Nonsense,” said Botax. “You must allow room for natural variation. I will put it to the creature herself.”
>
> He turned to Marge, “Madam, is your bosom imperfect?

The story has appeared in many, many anthologies. I forget where I first read it, but the copy I used for the quote above was from [Nightfall Two](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24171). [It can be read online at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v35n03_1961-03_UnkSc-cape1736/page/n29/mode/2up) (thanks to [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111) for the link).

Comment: And it ends with the couple "getting it on" and one of the aliens shouting to his captain "look what they're doing" I think.

Comment: @sueelleker Yes, indeed ! But too late for the captain to see, fortunately for mankind ! ;)

Comment: As far as I know this was the only other time (besides “The Gods Themselves” a decade later, of course) that Asimov touched on sex in a work of Science Fiction.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Well, there's "I'm in Marsport without Hilda"

Comment: And plenty of touches (as it were) in his later works, such as _The Robots Of Dawn_, and _Foundation And Earth_.

Comment: @EuroMicelli they're at it like rabbits in Foundation and Earth. It's a key plot point.

Comment: Don't forget the ending of "Sally."  Not explicit, but definitely intentional.